# Combobox with two separate text fields per item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to store two items per item e.g. Name and description.
in the combobox the selected item will show the Name and a label will show the description for the item, whenever the selected item is changed the label needs to update.

What I have below seems to store the items but not display them based on the selected index or whenever the item selection is changed!

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "A1";
            item.Value = "A2";
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

            item.Text = "B1";
            item.Value = "B2";
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);


            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            label1.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();



        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString();
        }
```

And a Class with:

```
    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you expect the output to be either of `B1` or `A1`?

Comment: Unless the "description" is the identifying `Value` then it sounds like you want to store *three* data elements, not two.

Comment: the combo Box would show A1 and the label A2 at load, if they select B1 then the label should update with B2

Comment: @David the user will select A1 or B1... which will be unique values on selecting A1 or B1 the corresponding A2 or B2 is displayed in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBoxItem` is reference type. You have to create new item before adding it to `comboBox1` items Otherwise it will also change the previous added items.

Change this part

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "A1";
item.Value = "A2";
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

// Will change value of item thus item added to combo box will change too because the references are same
item.Text = "B1"; 
item.Value = "B2";
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

To this

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "A1";
item.Value = "A2";
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

ComboboxItem item2 = new ComboboxItem();
item2.Text = "B1";
item2.Value = "B2";
comboBox1.Items.Add(item2);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had totally missed that! now it all works.